# How to express constraints involving array slicing by GEKKO variables?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gekko

I'm trying to solve a balls-in-bins-type problem using Gekko:

- I have `N` bins that `t` items will be thrown into following some distribution
- I need to 1) group the slots into `k` buckets 2) decide how many queries to make to each bucket to satisfy my constraints

I want to minimize the following objective:

[image]

Here is a MWE of what I have without many of the constraints:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

# Initialize model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Solver params
k = 2
dist = [0.5, 0.25, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625]
N = len(dist)
t = 100

# Initialize variables (hardcoding # of buckets = 2 for readability)
#
# Bucket boundaries 
cutoffs = [
    m.Var(0, lb=0, ub=0, integer=True),
    m.Var(3, lb=1, ub=N-1, integer=True),
    m.Var(N, lb=N, ub=N, integer=True),
]

# Number of queries to each bucket
queries = [m.Var(50, lb=1, integer=True) for _ in range(k)]

# Enforce that the cutoffs define distinct buckets
for i in range(k):
    m.Equation(cutoffs[i] < cutoffs[i+1])

# Enforce we have enough queries to actually recover everything
m.Equation(m.sum(queries) >= t)
   
# Objective function: Size of each bucket * queries to it
m.Minimize(m.sum([(cutoffs[i + 1] - cutoffs[i]) * queries[i] for i in range(k)]))

# Solve
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()

# Results
print('\n\n-------\n\n')
msg = "Buckets: \n"
for i in range(k):
    msg += f"\t* ({cutoffs[i].value[0]}, {cutoffs[i+1].value[0]}): " \
           f"{queries[i].value[0]}\n"

print(msg)
```

My first issue is that the simplified code above doesn't work depending on the initial values of `cutoffs`: if I start by initially making two equally-sized buckets, GEKKO outputs an incorrect solution (it should set one bucket to size 1 and place 99 queries there). I'm assuming there's just some sensitivity setting I need to adjust here?

My second, and more fundamental issue, is I'm struggling to figure out how to express constraints that utilize the probability mass of the buckets. In particular, I need to calculate something akin to: `bucket_mass = sum(dist[cutoff[i]:cutoff[i+1]])` in my constraints, but there doesn't appear to be a nice way to do that in GEKKO.

I attempted to do some form of masking solution:

```py
# Compute probability mass of each bucket
masses = [m.Intermediate(0), m.Intermediate(0)]
for i in range(k):
    # Add the weight of a distribution element only if it's within the bounds
    # of the current bucket
    for j in range(N):
        lb = m.if3(j - cutoffs[i], 0, 1)
        ub = m.if3(cutoffs[i + 1] - j - 1, 0, 1)
        masses[i] += dist[i] * lb * ub

# Example constraint: each bucket should have at least as many queries as the
# expected number of items that fall into it
for i in range(k):
    m.Equation(t * masses[i] <= queries[i])
```

but this example doesn't actually work for some reason + it blows up the # of variables way too much for the size of problems I'm considering

Any guidance someone can provide would be helpful! Sorry for the long post, I tried to cut it down as much as possible.